# Lots of errors after site is deployed

Tags: error-handling, deployment

Hello StackOverflow community,

I'm a business owner with a grasp on development, though not a coder myself. We've encountered a recurring problem in our workflow. Whenever our developers finish a feature or bug fix on their local machines, everything works as expected. However, when they commit and push their code to Git, we often run into issues that consume approximately 20% of our entire project timeline to resolve.

**Background**:

- We're a small organization.
- Our current workflow involves developers building and testing features on their local machines, and then pushing the stable version to Git.
- This problem persists across multiple development environments.

I understand there could be a myriad of factors leading to these issues, but I'm looking to understand common pitfalls or best practices that we might be overlooking.

Could anyone provide insights or recommend strategies to ensure smoother transitions from local development to our Git repository?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This isn't how Stack Overflow works.  You ask a specific programming question.  Your question would take a long discussion, which is offtopic here.  You can ask a specific question about one of your errors.

Comment: I completely understand. But I am facing this situation with almost every project. There must be some flaws in my workflow. I am sorry if it's off-topic, but I certainly need guidance here and I believe, there's no other platform than Stackoverflow to counter any challenges in the development ecosystem.

Comment: I think the DevOps StackExchange might be able to help you?